# After getting Class Instance List, how to get exact point of Memory leak in Reference using Android Studio Profiler?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-profiler

I have memory leaks in my project. To find out leaks, I have decided to use Android Studio Profiler. After a lot of research about it. I stuck in between Instance List and Reference how to identify exact leak point.

Below is the screen shot of my profiler:

[Memory Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0ngY.png)

Please help me to understand exact leak cause to avoid Memory Leaks.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio's memory profiler detects a specific class of leaks when you retain an activity or fragment past its life cycle.

The `References` tab shows how the leaked activity or fragment is being retained. You can try clicking on `Show nearest GC root only` to see the shortest path to GC root, which may give you some insight into how to stop retaining the object and eliminate the leak.